# How to call one function in every activity of android project?

Tags: android, function, notifications

I have a one notification service which fires at every 5 seconds and get the data and parse it and then display it..
But this mechanism works only for the home screen of the app.

I want this to be done in every screen of the app.For that should i write the same code in every activity of the project ? It is very tedious job . I want to make it generalize ..

How to do that ?? any ideas??

Answer (score 4):

you can make `BasicActivity` and have method in that `Activity` and call that method inside `onCreate();`

now extend every Activity in your project from your `BasicActivity`

If you are talking push notification service, this idea seems to problematic. tell us more what are you exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

you do something like this in some utility class

```
public static void showNotifction(Activity a)
{
 //notify

}
```

and over this if you have any call back methods.. Then create an interface with those methods and implement them in all those Activities and you can do this..

```
 public static void showNotifction(CommoInterface a)
    {
     if(a insatncof Activity){
     //notify
      a.callBack(); // callBack is a method in the interface..
     }

    }
```